# HTML + CSS: Indent a paragraph after icon

Tags: html, css, icons, indentation, paragraph

One for all you web designers...

I would like to display a character and indent a paragraph after it - just like in the diagram here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43015072/indent.jpg

The trick is, I would like to do this without:

- Using a table
- Specifying a div height

The single character is rendered into an icon using an icon font (@font-face). Does anyone have any suggestions about how to go about doing this using only HTML + CSS?

Comment: Have you thought about custom bullet point characters http://ask.metafilter.com/156206/Using-a-character-as-a-custom-list-bullet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came out with this:

```
p {
    padding-left:20px; /* adjust it to your custom font needings */
    position:relative;
}
p:before {
    content: "x";
    font-family:Arial; /* add your custom font here */
    position:absolute;
    left:5px; /* adjust it to your custom font needings */
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/283XX/)

---

If you actually need the borders, wrap the text in a span:

```
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</span></p>​
```

and add this rule:

```
p {
    /* same as before */
    border:1px solid red;
}
p span {
    display:block;
    border-left:1px solid red;
    padding-left:5px; /* or whatever you want */
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/NCEQq/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <style type="text/css">
    #con{margin:0 auto; width:700px;}
    #left{height:auto;float:left; width:100px;}
    #right{height:auto; float:right;  width:600px; } 
  </style>
  <div id="con">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
```